# Importing Form using Context_processors

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to set up a variable that contains a form which I can use in my footer which is in base.html. I was thinking of using context_processor to create a variable but I must be missing something after several hours of trying I need help.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from .forms import SignUpForm
from .models import SignUp

def SignUp(request):
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "", context)
```

context_processor.py

```
from .forms import SignUp

def SignUpFormGlobal(request):
    newsletter = SignUp()
    return {
        'signup': newsletter 
    }
```

base.html

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ signup }}
    <input class='btn btn-default' type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your templates `signup` is a function takes a request parameter (a django view function). It looks like what you want to do instead is make your `signup` variable a Django form instead.

```
# context_processor.py
def SignUpFormGlobal(request):
    return {
        'signup_form': SignUpForm()
    }
```

In your templates, the form should appear properly

```
<form action="{% url 'sign-up-view' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ signup_form.as_p }}
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You'll also need to update your `TEMPLATE` settings to ensure that the context_processor is being used.

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    ....
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'myproject.context_processors.SignUpFormGlobal',
            ....
        ],
    },
}]
```

Comment: Thank you i do not know how I did not realize that but thank you it worked!